# Why won't the browser cache my http response?

Tags: http, caching, browser

I have a REST api developed with `django-tastypie`. I have a couple of resources that are quite heavy but are not mutable, so I would like the browser to cache them to avoid unnecesary requests.

I've set the `HTTP Expire` header to a date far two years in the future, this is what the browser gets:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Wed, 16 May 2012 17:29:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Expires: Tue, 06 May 2014 17:29:33 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, public
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 1051
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=82
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I'm using `jQuery.ajax` to issue the request. The expires header looks good, but the request is made each time I refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

`Cache-Control: no-cache`

from the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1):

> This allows an origin server to prevent caching even by caches that
>   have been configured to return stale responses to client requests.

Comment: That worked, thank you!. Additionally, I found out that current versions of `django-tastypie` force the `Cache-Control: no-cache` header. So I had to change that according to this pull request: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/pull/380

Answer (score 0):

If this content can change, try to use ifModified: true in the jQuery.ajax

Answer (score 0):

In your .ajax call, set the cache: attribute to true, like this:

$.ajax({
        url: postUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: true, /* this should be true by default, but in your case I would check this*/
        data: stuff
    });